# How to insert image in azure cosmos db (Document DB)

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, uwp, azure-cosmosdb

I am using **xamarin** with **UWP** and I want to insert an image into azure **cosmos DB(Document DB)**.

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: When creating a Cosmos DB, you choose an API. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am selected SQL(DocumentDB) and want to store image into it.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the reason to use a documentdb to store a image? If Azure blob storage is acceptable, we could use [Azure storage blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) to do that.

Comment: Yes azure storage blob did the same but i want to store/insert image into database

Comment: If you want  to use Azure documentdb attachment, please refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createattachmentasync.aspx) and this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0cfa7919-ef54-4735-a002-754335503ece/storing-attachments-in-azure-documentdb-and-retriving-them-seems-to-be-broken?forum=AzureDocumentDB)

Answer (score 8):

some code

```js
var myDoc = new { id = "42", Name = "Max", City="Aberdeen" }; // this is the document you are trying to save
var attachmentStream = File.OpenRead("c:/Path/To/File.pdf"); // this is the document stream you are attaching

var client = await GetClientAsync();
var createUrl = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName);
Document document = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(createUrl, myDoc);

await client.CreateAttachmentAsync(document.SelfLink, attachmentStream, new MediaOptions()
    {
        ContentType = "application/pdf", // your application type
        Slug = "78", // this is actually attachment ID
    });
```

Source: [Source of code](http://tech.trailmax.info/2017/05/working-with-attachments-in-documentdb/)

How i found that:  [Link for research](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=documentdb%20attachments)

In a not been funny way, but rather in a link that won't expire and gives you other results pointing in the right direction.

======

I use azure,   if you go putting images into documentDb, you will pay high for the query cost.   Its built in to do it, but essentially it would be normal practice to use Azure blob and save the link in a field, and then have a viewmodel that would return  either the link ( if it's public )  or the binary data if not.

By tying into attachments, you are further pinning your code into only been able to work on DocumentDb.

Comment: Adding to Dave's answer, if you store the image in Azure Blob and add the link in the Cosmos DB document you can take advantage of things like [Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn) that will make your images load faster for your mobile clients.